# How to get All the elements of the entity in spring-boot ?

Tags: java, spring, angular, spring-boot, angular5

I'm sending a GET request from angular5 to spring-boot to get all the elements of the entity Contrat below  .

This is the entity :

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Contrat implements Serializable{

        @Id @GeneratedValue
        private Long id;
        private Date dateDebut ;
        private Date dateFin ;
        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "Id_Project")
        @JsonBackReference(value="projet-contrat")
        private Project project;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "Id_AppUser")
        @JsonBackReference(value="appuser-contrat")
        private AppUser appUser;
}
```

This is the repository :

```
  public interface ContratRepo extends JpaRepository<Contrat,Long> {

    @Query("select from Contrat c where c.appUser = :userApp")
    public Page<Contrat> chercherContrat(@Param("userApp") AppUser userApp  
   , Pageable pageable);

   }
```

In Angular5 the console.log(data) returns this result for exemple:

```
 {id: 1, dateDebut: 1526083200000, dateFin: 1526083200000}
```

So as you can see there is not the project element (that i need in front-end) .

I want to show in angular the contrat elements plus some information of the project related to .

Any idea ?

Comment: You will have to excuse me if I'm being over zealous, but you are breaking one of the OWASP top-ten rules, so hopefully you are not putting this code on the internet. You should never expose primary keys from a database in the front-end, and especially when they are auto generated by the database. In OWASP 2013 this was known as **Insecure Direct Object References** in OWASP 2017 you can find it as **A5-2017: Broken Access Control**. Personally I always use a DTO when transporting data to the front-end. There are a lot of SO posts on DTOs and entities that you can read for more details.

Comment: Thank you for these useful interesting information , i will absolutely read about that , so you mean when we see number column in web app table or any others , it doesnt mean the one in database right ? I was always using the one in database

Answer (score 0):

In place of jpaRepositiry you could use PagingAndSorting repository to get all the related entity details via findAll api .

Comment: can you please explaine more?

Comment: Please refer spring boot documentation .